# Plotting Ellipsoid with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Does anyone have sample code for plotting ellipsoids? There is one for sphere on `matplotlib` site, but nothing for ellipsoids. I am trying to plot

```
x**2 + 2*y**2 + 2*z**2 = c
```

where `c` is a constant (like 10) that defines an ellipsoid. I tried the `meshgrid(x,y)` route, reworked the equation so `z` is on one side, but the `sqrt` is a problem. The `matplotlib` sphere example works with angles, `u,v`, but I am not sure how to work that for ellipsoid.

Comment: @tillsten: The reference that you give describes how to plot an *ellipse*, while the question is about an *ellipsoid*, which is the three-dimensional equivalent of an ellipse.

Comment: EOL: You're right, i'll remove my comment.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is how you can do it via spherical coordinates:

```
# from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # Not needed with Matplotlib 3.6.3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))  # Square figure
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

coefs = (1, 2, 2)  # Coefficients in a0/c x**2 + a1/c y**2 + a2/c z**2 = 1 
# Radii corresponding to the coefficients:
rx, ry, rz = 1/np.sqrt(coefs)

# Set of all spherical angles:
u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

# Cartesian coordinates that correspond to the spherical angles:
# (this is the equation of an ellipsoid):
x = rx * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = ry * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = rz * np.outer(np.ones_like(u), np.cos(v))

# Plot:
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b')

# Adjustment of the axes, so that they all have the same span:
max_radius = max(rx, ry, rz)
for axis in 'xyz':
    getattr(ax, 'set_{}lim'.format(axis))((-max_radius, max_radius))

plt.show()
```

The resulting plot is similar to

[image]

The program above actually produces a nicer looking "square" graphics.

This solution is strongly inspired from the [example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo2.html) in [Matplotlib's gallery](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html).

Comment: thanks for this answer. The axis adjustment lines gave me an error however, "AttributeError: 'Axes3DSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_zlim'". Is it because I am on older version of matplotlib (I am on 1.0.1)

Comment: yep that was the problem. I upgraded to 1.1.0 and it all works now.

Comment: rx, ry, rz = 1/np.sqrt(coef) Should be rx, ry, rz = 1/np.sqrt(coefs)

Comment: If I have semi-major axis as a and c, semi minor axes as b, will the coeff be (1/a**2,1/b**2,1/c**2) ?

Comment: Yes. Of course in that case you can directly do `rx, ry, rz = a, b, c` (no need for coefficients `coefs`).

Comment: For those, like me, who didn't initially understand how `np.outer` works here, use this instead: `u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100); v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100); u,v = np.meshgrid(u,v,indexing='ij'); x = rx * np.cos(u) * np.sin(v); y = ry * np.sin(u) * np.sin(v); z = rz * np.cos(v)`

Comment: It seems like ```from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D``` is not used.

Comment: Indeed. At the time of writing this answer, I understood that this import was needed for initializing something internal to Matplotlib. As of Matplotlib 3.6.3, it doesn't appear to be necessary.

Answer (score 20):

Building on EOL's answer. Sometimes you have an ellipsoid in matrix format:

A and c Where A is the ellipsoid matrix and c is a vector representing the centre of the ellipsoid.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as linalg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# your ellispsoid and center in matrix form
A = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,0,2]])
center = [0,0,0]

# find the rotation matrix and radii of the axes
U, s, rotation = linalg.svd(A)
radii = 1.0/np.sqrt(s)

# now carry on with EOL's answer
u = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0.0, np.pi, 100)
x = radii[0] * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = radii[1] * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = radii[2] * np.outer(np.ones_like(u), np.cos(v))
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x)):
        [x[i,j],y[i,j],z[i,j]] = np.dot([x[i,j],y[i,j],z[i,j]], rotation) + center

# plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z,  rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b', alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
del fig
```

So, not too much new here, but helpful if you've got an ellipsoid in matrix form which is rotated and perhaps not centered at 0,0,0 and want to plot it.

Comment: Hi, why you need to compute the inverse square root of the singular values, instead of just the square root, to get the radii?  I mean why radii = 1.0/np.sqrt(s) instead of 
radii = np.sqrt(s). I think the later gives the correct radii.

Answer (score 7):

If you have an ellipsoid specified by an arbitrary covariance matrix `cov` and offset `bias`, you perform a simpler version of [@minillinim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14958796/2988730) by vectorizing the operations.

Starting with

```
u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
```

Make a unit sphere

```
x = np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = np.outer(np.ones_like(u), np.cos(v))
sphere = np.stack((x, y, z), axis=-1)[..., None]
```

Compute the standard deviation matrix, which has the same rotation as the covariance, but scales by the square root of the eigenvalues:

```
e, v = np.linalg.eig(cov)
s = v @ np.diag(np.sqrt(e)) @ v.T
```

Now transform the sphere:

```
ellipsoid = (s @ sphere).squeeze(-1) + bias
```

You can plot the result pretty much as before:

```
ax.plot_surface(*ellipsoid.transpose(2, 0, 1), rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b', alpha=0.75)
```

For reference, `u`, `v` have shape `(100,)`, which makes `x`, `y`, `z` into `(100, 100)` arrays. `sphere` is `(100, 100, 3, 1)`, which makes it a 100x100 array of 3x1 vectors as far as the broadcasting `@` operator is concerned. `s @ sphere` has the same size, so squeezing out the last unit axis makes it suitable for broadcasting for addition with `bias`. Finally, `ellipsoid.transpose(2, 0, 1)` has shape `(3, 100, 100)`, which can be star-expanded as three separate arrays of x-, y- and z-values into the call to `plot_surface`.

Comment: When I do this, I get a sample covariance ellipsoid which is quite a bit larger than the sampled points. Is there a way to scale it to a confidence interval?

Comment: This answer is a little bit of a hack Take zero mean random vector X with covariance matrix is C = < X X’>. C can be decomposed as RLR’ where R is the rotation matrix of eigenvectors and L is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. With S = \sqrt{L} we have C = RSS’R’$. Suppose N is a normal random vector so that < NN’> = I. We can transform N into X by X = RSN. This is confirmed because <X X’> = <RS N N’R’> = RS < N N’>S’R’ = RSIS’ R’ = C. So the “proper” transformation to be done is X = RSN.

Comment: However, in this case you get away with it because our “dataset” is the points on a sphere. When you act R’ on that you get the same set of points back, so your transformation C = RSS'R' is effectively the transformation RSS’. This is almost RS like it should be, you just scale the data twice by S instead of once. This is why Translunar complains that the covariance ellipsoid is not scaled appropriately to the data.

So this method does give you an ellipsoid with almost the correct shape, but like I say it's a little bit of a hack.

Comment: @Jagerber48. You are absolutely right. I fixed the answer to account for the mistake.

Comment: @Translunar. Yes. Couple of years late, but the updated answer should be correct now.