# Needed explaination for plotting Ellipsoid with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

This question is in direct reference to [Plotting Ellipsoid with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819498/plotting-ellipsoid-with-matplotlib).

I need to model an ellipsoid in 4 or higher dimension.

I need to understand the answer in the above question so I can extend it to solve my prob. How are these lines of code working :

```
# Cartesian coordinates that correspond to the spherical angles:
# (this is the equation of an ellipsoid):
x = rx * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = ry * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = rz * np.outer(np.ones_like(u), np.cos(v))
```

I need the answer : How was the cos(u) and sin(v) etc chosen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe it is more a mathematical problem than a Python one.

Comment: @Simpom I think users who have used this (many must have, since this is part of the learning module for 3d plotting on the matplotlib site) can answer my question so I can extend to higher Dimensions

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How do I shift it there? Should I ask it again there or is there a way to link it?