# How can I make a 3D plot in matplotlib of an ellipsoid defined by a quadratic equation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, ellipse, quadratic-curve

I have the general formula of an ellipsoid:

```
A*x**2 + C*y**2 + D*x + E*y + B*x*y + F + G*z**2 = 0
```

where A,B,C,D,E,F,G are constant factors.

How can I plot this equation as a 3D plot in matplotlib? (A wireframe would be best.)

I saw this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819498/plotting-ellipsoid-with-matplotlib) but it is in parametric form and I am not sure how to put the z-coordinates in this code. Is there a way to keep the general form to plot this without the parametric form?

I started to put this in some kind of code like this:

```py
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x, y):
    return ((A*x**2 + C*y**2 + D*x + E*y + B*x*y + F))

def f(z):
    return G*z**2

x = np.linspace(-2200, 1850, 30)
y = np.linspace(-100, 60, 30)
z = np.linspace(-100, 60, 30)

X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z');
```

I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-95b1296ae6a4> in <module>()
     18 fig = plt.figure()
     19 ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
---> 20 ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10)
     21 ax.set_xlabel('x')
     22 ax.set_ylabel('y')

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py in plot_wireframe(self, X, Y, Z, *args, **kwargs)
   1847         had_data = self.has_data()
   1848         if Z.ndim != 2:
-> 1849             raise ValueError("Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.")
   1850         # FIXME: Support masked arrays
   1851         X, Y, Z = np.broadcast_arrays(X, Y, Z)

ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.
```

Answer (score 2):

Side note, but what you have is not the most general equation for a 3d ellipsoid. Your equation can be rewritten as

```
A*x**2 + C*y**2 + D*x + E*y + B*x*y = - G*z**2 - F,
```

which means that in effect for each value of `z` you get a different level of a 2d ellipse, and the slices are symmetric with respect to the `z = 0` plane. This shows how your ellipsoid is not general, and it helps check the results to make sure that what we get makes sense.

Assuming we take a general point `r0 = [x0, y0, z0]`, you have

```
r0 @ M @ r0 + b0 @ r0 + c0 == 0
```

where

```
M = [ A    B/2    0
     B/2    C     0
      0     0     G],
b0 = [D, E, 0],
c0 = F
```

where [`@` stands for matrix-vector or vector-vector product](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html).

You could take your function and [plot its isosurface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030098/how-to-display-a-3d-plot-of-a-3d-array-isosurface-in-matplotlib-mplot3d-or-simil), but that would be suboptimal: you would need a gridded approximation for your function which is very expensive to do to sufficient resolution, and you'd have to choose the domain for this sampling wisely.

Instead you can perform a [principal axis transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_axis_theorem) on your data to generalize the [parametric plot of a canonical ellipsoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819498/plotting-ellipsoid-with-matplotlib) that you yourself linked.

The first step is to diagonalize `M` as `M = V @ D @ V.T`, where `D` is [diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix). Since it's a real symmetric matrix this is always possible and `V` is [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix). Then we have

```
r0 @ V @ D @ V.T @ r0 + b0 @ r0 + c0 == 0
```

which we can regroup as

```
(V.T @ r0) @ D @ (V.T @ r0) + b0 @ V @ (V.T @ r0) + c0 == 0
```

which motivates the definition of the auxiliary coordinates `r1 = V.T @ r0` and vector `b1 = b0 @ V`, for which we get

```
r1 @ D @ r1 + b1 @ r1 + c0 == 0.
```

Since `D` is a symmetric matrix with the eigenvalues `d1, d2, d3` in its diagonal, the above is the equation

```
d1 * x1**2 + d2 * x2**2 + d3 * x3**3 + b11 * x1 + b12 * x2 + b13 * x3 + c0 == 0
```

where `r1 = [x1, x2, x3]` and `b1 = [b11, b12, b13]`.

What's left is to switch from `r1` to `r2` such that we remove the linear terms:

```
d1 * (x1 + b11/(2*d1))**2 + d2 * (x2 + b12/(2*d2))**2 + d3 * (x3 + b13/(2*d3))**2 - b11**2/(4*d1) - b12**2/(4*d2) - b13**2/(4*d3) + c0 == 0
```

So we define

```
r2 = [x2, y2, z2]
x2 = x1 + b11/(2*d1)
y2 = y1 + b12/(2*d2)
z2 = z1 + b13/(2*d3)
c2 = b11**2/(4*d1) b12**2/(4*d2) b13**2/(4*d3) - c0.
```

For these we finally have

```
d1 * x2**2 + d2 * y2**2 + d3 * z2**2 == c2,
d1/c2 * x2**2 + d2/c2 * y2**2 + d3/c2 * z2**2 == 1
```

which is the canonical form of a second-order surface. In order for this to meaningfully correspond to an ellipsoid we must ensure that `d1`, `d2`, `d3` and `c2` are all strictly positive. If this is guaranteed then the semi-major axes of the canonical form are `sqrt(c2/d1)`, `sqrt(c2/d2)` and `sqrt(c2/d3)`.

So here's what we do:

1. ensure that the parameters correspond to an ellipsoid
2. generate a theta and phi mesh for polar and azimuthal angles
3. compute the transformed coordinates `[x2, y2, z2]`
4. shift them back (by `r2 - r1`) to get `[x1, y1, z1]`
5. transform the coordinates back by `V` to get `r0`, the actual `[x, y, z]` coordinates we're interested in.

Here's how I'd implement this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def get_transforms(A, B, C, D, E, F, G): 
    """ Get transformation matrix and shift for a 3d ellipsoid 

    Assume A*x**2 + C*y**2 + D*x + E*y + B*x*y + F + G*z**2 = 0, 
    use principal axis transformation and verify that the inputs 
    correspond to an ellipsoid. 

    Returns: (d, V, s) tuple of arrays 
        d: shape (3,) of semi-major axes in the canonical form 
           (X/d1)**2 + (Y/d2)**2 + (Z/d3)**2 = 1 
        V: shape (3,3) of the eigensystem 
        s: shape (3,) shift from the linear terms 
    """ 

    # construct original matrix 
    M = np.array([[A, B/2, 0], 
                  [B/2, C, 0], 
                  [0, 0, G]]) 
    # construct original linear coefficient vector 
    b0 = np.array([D, E, 0]) 
    # constant term 
    c0 = F 

    # compute eigensystem 
    D, V = np.linalg.eig(M) 
    if (D <= 0).any(): 
        raise ValueError("Parameter matrix is not positive definite!") 

    # transform the shift 
    b1 = b0 @ V 

    # compute the final shift vector 
    s = b1 / (2 * D) 

    # compute the final constant term, also has to be positive 
    c2 = (b1**2 / (4 * D)).sum() - c0 
    if c2 <= 0: 
        print(b1, D, c0, c2) 
        raise ValueError("Constant in the canonical form is not positive!")

    # compute the semi-major axes 
    d = np.sqrt(c2 / D) 

    return d, V, s 

def get_ellipsoid_coordinates(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, n_theta=20, n_phi=40): 
    """Compute coordinates of an ellipsoid on an ellipsoidal grid 

    Returns: x, y, z arrays of shape (n_theta, n_phi) 
    """ 

    # get canonical grid 
    theta,phi = np.mgrid[0:np.pi:n_theta*1j, 0:2*np.pi:n_phi*1j] 
    r2 = np.array([np.sin(theta) * np.cos(phi), 
                   np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi), 
                   np.cos(theta)]) # shape (3, n_theta, n_phi) 

    # get transformation data 
    d, V, s = get_transforms(A, B, C, D, E, F, G)  # could be *args I guess 

    # shift and transform back the coordinates 
    r1 = d[:,None,None]*r2 - s[:,None,None]  # broadcast along first of three axes
    r0 = (V @ r1.reshape(3, -1)).reshape(r1.shape)  # shape (3, n_theta, n_phi) 

    return r0  # unpackable to x, y, z of shape (n_theta, n_phi)
```

Here's an example with an ellipsoid and proof that it works:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G = args = 2, -1, 2, 3, -4, -3, 4 
x,y,z = get_ellipsoid_coordinates(*args) 
print(np.allclose(A*x**2 + C*y**2 + D*x + E*y + B*x*y + F + G*z**2, 0))  # True
```

The actual plotting from here is trivial. Using the [3d scaling hack from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10328142/5067311) to preserve equal axes:

```
# create 3d axes
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# plot the data
ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

# scaling hack
bbox_min = np.min([x, y, z])
bbox_max = np.max([x, y, z])
ax.auto_scale_xyz([bbox_min, bbox_max], [bbox_min, bbox_max], [bbox_min, bbox_max])

plt.show()
```

Here's how the result looks:
[image: figure of an ellipsoid that's flattened and rotated around the z axis]

Rotating it around it's nicely visible that the surface is indeed reflection symmetric with respect to the `z = 0` plane, which was evident from the equation.

You can change the `n_theta` and `n_phi` keyword arguments to the function to generate a grid with a different mesh. The fun thing is that you can take *any* scattered points lying on the unit sphere and plug it into the definition of `r2` in the function `get_ellipsoid_coordinates` (as long as this array has a first dimension of size 3), and the output coordinates will have the same shape, but they will be transformed onto the actual ellipsoid.

You can also use other libraries to visualize the surface, for instance mayavi where you can either plot the surface we just computed, or [compare it with an isosurface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6031871/5067311) which is built-in there.